# Could not parse audio file track1.m4a

Tags: ruby, libgosu

Interrupt message:
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/gosu-1.4.3/lib/gosu/compat.rb:116:in `initialize': Could not parse audio file track1.m4a (RuntimeError)
: Couldn't open track1.m4a
I'm trying to open some tracks in Ruby using Gosu, but the system does not accept the file. May I ask why and how to fix the problem?

I've tried to input the file using Gosu::Song.new but the interrupt message appeared. I was expecting it load the media files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting the audio file into .mp3 or .ogg files. Ruby does not accept mp4 or m4.A

Comment: thannks for your answer, I've solved the problem.